# NSMenu delegate does not trigger menuWillOpen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenu, nsstatusbar

I've got an Interface Builder NSMenu-Object. I added my custom Class "StatusBarMenu".

The `StatusBarMenu.h` file looks like this:

```
@interface StatusBarMenu : NSMenu <NSMenuDelegate>
```

The `StatusBarMenu.c` file looks like this:

```
- (void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu {
    `NSLog(@"open");`
}
```

The Menu is assigned in the `AppDelegate.c` as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.statusBar = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    self.statusBar.highlightMode = YES;
    [self.statusBar setMenu:self.statusMenu];
}
```

And the `AppDelegate.h`:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "StatusBarMenu.h"
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSStatusItem *statusBar;
@property (weak) IBOutlet StatusBarMenu *statusMenu;
```

The Menu opens, but menuWillOpen is not called.
Did i miss anything?

I appreciate any help! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the delegate, either in Interface Builder by a connection (`statusMenu` > `delegate` to `AppDelegate`) or in code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

```
self.statusMenu.delegate = self;
```

Comment: What if I have multiple windows of different type, some of which should handle opening that menu (in the main menu bar) differently? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/55987213/43615